# get list of programs in system tray

Tags: c#, winapi, system-tray

I want to get a list (handle is enough) of the programs currently in the system tray.

I searched the internet and I found one solution - to get the System Tray Handle and then `TB_BUTTONCOUNT` + `TB_GETBUTTON`.

The solution above works only in XP and I think Vista (didnt try, but thats what people says + it doesnt work on my computer which uses windows 8.1)

Is there a solution that works for all Operating Systems from XP and above to get the list I want?

Comment: I assume this is the solution you tried: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4c4f60ce-3573-433d-994e-9c17f95187f0/finding-which-applications-and-services-are-listed-in-the-system-tray?forum=csharpgeneral?

Comment: And that you had a look at this stuff, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10497/A-tool-to-order-the-window-buttons-in-your-taskbar. From what I can see I don't see any mention of it not working on 8.1, they do mention doing a check for > XP

Comment: @TomHeard Do you expect an article from 2005 to mention that it won't work on 8.1?

Comment: @hvd Sorry didn't check the date. I just did a quick scan read. I was actually more wondering if this was the solution that he was talking about and if he had tried it.

Comment: @TomHeard Ah, okay. The comments point out problems on Vista and Windows 7, so I'm not optimistic about 8.1.

Comment: Ok then, so then sounds very similar to what the OP has tried.

Comment: Given your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427917/wpf-dont-allow-to-close-deactive-lose-focus-from-specific-window), it sounds an awful lot like you're trying to create something that most people would consider malware. If it's done with the consent of the user, you don't need all these hacks, you can just configure Windows to be locked down. If it's done without the consent of the user, I hope you get no help here.

Comment: @hvd honestly, there is no connection between both. I am doing a program like Fast Windows Hider and I want to be able to hide not only regular windows but programs in the system tray. about my other question, I am doin application for the army (yes I am a solider) and I need "kiosk mode" application...

Comment: @Ron That's good. In that case, it'll be with the consent of the user, and there are various configuration options in Windows that would prevent access to unauthorised applications, no need to do that from within your application.

Comment: @Ron As for this question, I'm not sure, but if your goal is to not only hide notification area icons but also their notifications, even if you manage to hide the icons, you won't have got what you're looking for, I think.

Comment: @hvd thats interesting. I didnt think about it so far.. I first wanted to get them which was obstacle, but now after you mentioned it, it really seems unnecessary

Comment: If you want kiosk mode, why don't you use, well, kiosk mode?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thats not related to this question but, I want kiosk mode for desktop application, not for windows store app

Comment: So use kiosk mode then. If you want kiosk mode, use kiosk mode. If you want kiosk mode, don't run in desktop mode and let people start any old applications.